# Unknown provider: PostProvider <- Post

Tags: angularjs, ruby-on-rails-4

i am new to angular and facing this exception when trying to retrieve a list of blog-posts from rails backend. 
can anyone help me please, i am unable to find the exact solution of this problem.

```
Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: PostProvider <- Post
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.22/$injector/unpr?p0=PostProvider%20%3C-%20Post
```

var myApp = angular.module('Emangu', ['ngRoute', 'ngResource']);

```
//Routes 

myApp.config([
  '$routeProvider', '$locationProvider', function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
    $routeProvider.when('/blog', {
      templateUrl: '/templates/posts/index.html',
      controller: 'PostListCtr'
    });
  }
]);

//Controllers

myApp.controller("PostListCtr", ['$scope', '$http', '$resource', 'Posts', 'Post', '$location', function ($scope, $http, $resource, Posts, Post, $location) {

    alert("hello");
    $scope.posts = Posts.query();
    $scope.deletePost = function (Post) {
        if (confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this Post?")) {
            Post.delete({ id: Post }, function () {
                $scope.posts = Posts.list();
                $location.path('/');
            });
        }
    };
}]);

//resources

myApp.factory('Posts', ['$resource', function ($resource) {
  return $resource('/posts.json', {}, {
    query: { method: 'GET', isArray: true },
    create: { method: 'POST' }
  })
}]);
```

Comment: And where is your `Post` provider?

Answer (score 1):

Add Post factory (service) or remove it from PostListCtr dependencies